# Changing version code in AndroidManifest not Working

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to update my app in the playstore, to do that I changed my versioncode from 1 to 2:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.xamaxon.congstardatenverbrauch"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1">
```

When I'm uploading the app the developerconsole is saying, that I still use the version code 1 and there is no human support for German developer, so I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: Yes more than just one time...
But I mentioned that there wasn't a version code in the Manifest of the first version could that be a problem?

Comment: Have you "Saved" your Manifest? When you export a new APK, it uses the saved files. If you use Eclipse, check that it doesn't have an asterisk "*" in the tab. Restarting eclipse may help, too

Comment: No the file was saved correctly

Comment: Does it fail to upload of fail to publish?

Comment: The upload is working, but when the developer consoles checks the file I got the error

Comment: im with you. Ich bin mit dir.

Comment: Same here. Changed from 1 to 2 but does not work at all.

Answer (score 22):

The version code and name get overridden by values in your `build.gradle` file. So edit your `build.gradle` and rebuild.

Comment: You can remove the version information from build.gradle and then the manifest will work

Comment: This was my problem too. Gosh, why do people want to do one thing multiple ways!

Comment: I dont have the version in build.gradle so this is not the only issue and fix

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would release the first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or minor release.

So, maybe the problem because you didn't set version code in manifest file in the first release.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Could you please give me the full message google play have said? And what to buttons appeard when that message appeared.

I remember that a similar message faced me, and maybe there was a continue button.

Comment: This aren't good news, I didn't cared about the first version code because I thought it was set automatic. :(

Comment: Try to release your app as beta version on google play, firstly. and what will be changed?

Comment: "Hochladen fehlgeschlagen
Sie müssen einen anderen Versionscode für Ihre APK-Datei verwenden, denn Sie haben bereits eine mit dem Versionscode 1."

translated to English it means:
"You have to use an other versioncode for your APK-File, because you already used the versioncode 1."

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you're in Android Studio, don't forget:
`Build` > `Generate Signed APK...`

Comment: Because if you follow all the steps outlined in other answers and don't do this you will waste a lot of time reupload ing the same apk over and over again. Do you agree?

Comment: as you can see what he wants to know why the developer console says it has version code 1 where he already updated it to version 2. not the problem in uploading a unsigned apk. please re-read then you can understand it. anyway there is a right answer i think here.

Comment: Yes, that can be the result of not generating a new signed apk in android studio. Try it yourself. Change the version number of one of your own apps in the manifest or gradle then try and upload it to google play. The developer console will give you the message that you need to change the version number. You then need to generate a new signed apk and it will work. Seriously, try it now.

Comment: why should you re-upload the old apk then? its common sense to upload the latest signed apk. i dont know whats on your mind.

Comment: @Secret Coder 
That's because like the other answers here you are blinded by the [Curse of Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge). If a new user (like myself) follows the instructions above to the letter then it will not work, you also have to add on the instructions I gave, do you agree? You need to generate a new signed apk, the previous answers, as far as I can tell, assume people will know that. Some people (me, a few days ago for example) might not. Hence it relates to the question. Upvote if you agree please. :D